# Convert SqlGeometry data from SQL directly to Tiles / PNG file

Tags: spatial-database, sql, sql-server, png, ogc

I would like to know a basic method for 'exporting' SqlGeometry data from SQL Server 2008 to a Tile Server / PNG File generator. I already have a Silverlight Map application which uses a Custom Tile layer to view Tiles. I would like to add another (this generated tiles) transparent layer of PNG files on top of my base layer.

The 'Spatial Results' in SQL Server Management Studio 'picture' needs to be converted to 256x256 tiles made up of PNG files, with a quadkey so it knows where to place it on the map.

Is there a basic 'quick and easy' way to do this? And, as data gets updated in SQL, the tiles needs to be re-generated.

Thanks a lot.

Cheerio

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it would be to use [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome)/GeoWebCache with [MS SQL Server extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/sqlserver.html).
Unfortunately, you will not get PNG files with quadkey as you aspect, but you get a service that can server tiles as a WMS-C/TMS standard which shouldn't be to difficult to implement into your application. Also it has possibility to re-render particular tiles as you requested.
Also, if you a doing an overlay with another layer, they have to be in the same coordinate system and projection, it is not just a question of location of the tiles.

As a starting point go here:

[Introduction to an Open Source Geostack](http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/)

[GeoServer](http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/geoserver.html#geoserver)

[GeoWebCache](http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/geowebcache.html#geowebcache)

You said that you are using Silverlight for you application, have a look at one project, [BruTile](http://brutile.codeplex.com/), that also uses Silverlight for mapping, maybe it can help you.